# Justifying the Four Noble Truths without rebirth

Tags: rebirth, four-noble-truths, secular-buddhism

In the article entitled [A Secular Evaluation of Rebirth](http://secularbuddhism.org/2013/05/29/a-secular-evaluation-of-rebirth/), Doug Smith, of the [Secular Buddhist Association](http://secularbuddhism.org/), wrote:

> It is for reasons such as these that any contemporary, scientifically
>   informed Buddhist practice should reject belief in rebirth and its
>   associated kammic causation. The Path is rich enough without them.

It appears that many [Secular Buddhists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secular_Buddhism) do not accept rebirth, while almost all other Buddhists do.

In the essay entitled [Dhamma Without Rebirth?](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/bodhi/bps-essay_06.html), well-known Tripitaka translator and scholar [Ven. Bodhi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhikkhu_Bodhi) conveyed the mainstream view of the Buddhist world:

> If we suspend our own predilections for the moment and instead go
>   directly to our sources, **we come upon the indisputable fact that the
>   Buddha himself taught rebirth and taught it as a basic tenet of his
>   teaching**. Viewed in their totality, the Buddha's discourses show us
>   that far from being a mere concession to the outlook prevalent in his
>   time or an Asiatic cultural contrivance, the doctrine of rebirth has
>   tremendous implications for the entire course of Dhamma practice,
>   affecting both the aim with which the practice is taken up and the
>   motivation with which it is followed through to completion.

If someone considers himself a Buddhist, we can assume that he accepts the [Four Noble Truths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_Noble_Truths) and the [Noble Eightfold Path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noble_Eightfold_Path). I guess this should apply to Secular Buddhists as well.

If there is no such thing as rebirth (or continuation of the stream of consciousness or mind after death, in a new life), then there is no need to end suffering by ending craving (third noble truth), through following the Noble Eightfold Path (fourth noble truth). Instead, it's much easier to commit suicide, or simply wait for natural death. **After all, if there is no rebirth, then at death, all suffering would end anyway, right?**

So, based on this, how do Secular Buddhists justify their acceptance of the Four Noble Truths and the Buddha's teachings in general, if they reject rebirth? How would the Four Noble Truths and Nibbana have any meaning or usefulness for them? Why would they choose to follow the Noble Eightfold Path, if death is a much simpler way to end suffering?

Comment: @ChrisW I disagree that this is a duplicate. This question asks how to justify the Four Noble Truth... up to the 8F Path, not just about suicide. The linked "Secular Buddhism and Suicide" post addresses part of the topic, if not completely lacking the depth and riches of the referred articles in this post. The OP clearly stated *...simply wait for natural death* also a valid way, not just suicide. I suggest to give that top linked as "related topic".

Comment: @ChrisW I also disagree that it's a duplicate because if the part on suicide is removed, the rest of the question is still valid and asks a previously unasked question

Comment: This question seems to me to be, "If you don't believe in rebirth, why bother with the 4NT, because instead of the 4NT you can end suffering by suicide?" ... and I think that is a duplicate. What is left in the question if the part on suicide is removed? If you remove "suicide" as an option, then the question is "Why does a secular Buddhist follow the 4NT?"

Comment: @ChrisW Yes. The question is about why does a secular Buddhist follow the 4NT, if at death, all sufferings would end (due to no rebirth)?

Comment: I still don't understand what you're asking ... unless you're asking about suicide, what does death or rebirth have to do with anything? People follow the 4NT when/while they're alive. Also if they don't follow the 4NT then perhaps they wouldn't be considered secular Buddhists (so "Buddhists follow the 4NT because that's the definition of a Buddhist"). Also the question you're suggesting might be a "polling question" i.e. "If you're a secular Buddhist (or even just agnostic about rebirth) why do you follow the 4NT?"

Comment: See this meta-topic: [Is “Why do secular Buddhists follow the 4NT?” a valid question?](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2180/254)

Comment: @ChrisW + OP: the 3rd Truth **ayam dukkha-nirodha, "this is the cessation of suffering"**, if the secular Buddhist rejects doctrine of rebirth, then death can replace the 4th Truth **Path**, whether natural or suicidal death. Hence, there's no need for the Path. Here the Path is Buddha Dhamma... I emphasize, this OP a very good question. It would be very enlightening if anyone, particularly the secular, give sound answer how the 4th Truth should be kept or even removed in the *secular doctrine*.

Comment: Perhaps the other way to ask this question is:  "must suffering be ended only by ending craving, or can it be ended by death?" If suffering cannot be ended by death, then this leaves us with the conclusion, that there definitely is rebirth.

Comment: I think *rebirth* is the bone in this OP; that's also why it's different from other linked OP. Yet I'm not seeing/concerning there's any measurable means to valid or invalid whether that is or not rebirth; this type of agruments are plenty in this forum. But more important, how does secular Buddhist make a *rounded Buddhist doctrines set* by rejecting rebirth. I see the original wording is perfect, except the moderator think that it has to be withdrawn or edited...

Comment: @Mishu米殊 I think it was an OK question, except that as currently written it's the same as a previous question (about secular buddhism and suicide), which has already been answered. If this question wasn't asking about suicide then I don't see why belief in rebirth might still be essential -- death doesn't "replace the path" before you die -- and if you want dukkha to cease before death then death isn't an option.

Comment: @ChrisW now I see... the blind spot here is that, in your mind, you already justified dukkha can be ended by practicing 8FP before death; without rebirth. yet without going through the justification process... how do you justify it? If justified without justification process than why 8FP? Why not playing Pokeman, or doing sit-ups or anything or any moral codes that can be practiced to end dukkha?? This is exactly what the value of this OP about, not asking to justify/disprove suicide, but justify "how 8FP can end dukkha without rebirth"... do you see the broadness rebirth implies... ?

Comment: @Mishu米殊 Perhaps the topic you're talking about is reflected in [this discussion](https://discourse.suttacentral.net/t/understanding-the-terms-rebirth-reincarnation-re-becoming/2406/9) which includes, `In secular Buddhist circles, it is quite normal to say that the four noble truths and dependent origination do not mention rebirth, and therefore that it could not be a central Buddhist teaching. But that idea falls apart as soon as you realize that taṇhā ponobbhavikā does not mean "The craving that makes for further becoming …" but "the craving that leads to rebirth".`

Comment: Anyway, if you think there is a question to be asked that isn't about rebirth-belief and suicide, can you edit the text of the question, to make that question plain and to remove any mention of suicide?

Comment: @ChrisW i'll pass the ball back to the OP... too much intellectual exercise is unhealthy to the mind ;)

Answer (score 1):

1. Anti-rebirthist = ucchedadiṭṭhi =  one **extreme**.
2. Rebirth-lover = sassatadiṭṭhi = another extreme.
3. **Profit**-follower = eightfold path  = middle way.

1st and 2nd see [brahmajālasutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/dn/dn.01.0.bodh.html).

3rd see [dhammacakkappavaḍḍhanasutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn56/sn56.011.than.html). *(I am in plan to re-translate this sutta, but I can't not done it now. So if something wrong, I am sorry. I can't not check it deeply now, because my english still not good enough.)*

> "There are these two extremes that are not to be indulged in by one
>   who has gone forth. Which two? That which is devoted to sensual
>   pleasure with reference to sensual objects: base, vulgar, common,
>   ignoble, **unprofitable**; and that which is devoted to self-affliction:
>   painful, ignoble, **unprofitable**. Avoiding both of these **extremes**, the
>   middle way realized by the Tathagata — producing vision, producing
>   knowledge — leads to calm, to direct knowledge, to self-awakening, to
>   Unbinding.
>
> "And what is the middle way realized by the Tathagata that — producing
>   vision, producing knowledge — leads to calm, to direct knowledge, to
>   self-awakening, to Unbinding? Precisely this Noble Eightfold Path:
>   right view, right contemplate, right speech, right action, right
>   livelihood, right effort, right mindfulness, right concentration. This
>   is the middle way realized by the Tathagata that — producing vision,
>   producing knowledge — leads to calm, to direct knowledge, to
>   self-awakening, to Unbinding.

### What is profit?

**6 profit**: self profit, the others' profit, public's profit (common interest), this life's profit, next life's profit, and nibbāna-profit. (pali for search: attattha, parattha, attaparattha, ditthadhammika, samparāyika, and paramattha.)

Self profit, the others' profit, and public's profit (common interest) are **done together** by sati.

> "Because of what I have said here, monks, you should train yourselves
>   such that the gifts of those whose requisites we use — the robes,
>   alms-bowl, chair, bed, and medicine as a support when sick — will have
>   great fruits, great merits [for the people who give them], and our
>   going forth will not be in vain, will be fruitful, will have a result.
>   Thus should you train yourselves, thoroughly seeing that **for your own**
>   **benefit**, monks, it is right to strive with **heedfulness**; thoroughly
>   seeing that **for the benefit of others**, monks, it is right to strive
>   with **heedfulness**; and thoroughly seeing that **for the benefit of both**,
>   monks, it is right to strive with **heedfulness**."

This life's profit and next life's profit are **done together** by sati (appamāda). So, person who do just this life's profit or next life profit is pamāda person. see:

http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn03/sn03.017.than.html

Nibbāna profit can be accessed by practitioner after he perfect finished to meditate magga.  And that magga can start to meditate after sīla is done.

> [SN 45.149](http://%20it%20is%20on%20dependence%20on%20virtue) Just as, bhikkhus, whatever actions are to be performed with
>   strength are all performed on dependence on the earth, supported by
>   the earth; in the same way, bhikkhus, **it is on dependence on virtue**,
>   supported by virtue, that a bhikkhu develops the **noble eightfold path (magga)**,
>   that he cultivates the noble eightfold path.

Above sīla give this life's profit and next life. See (1st-4th are this life's profit, 5th is next life's profit):

> [Mahāparinibbānasutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/dn/dn.16.1-6.vaji.html#para-1-23)
>   24. "Five blessings, householders, accrue to the righteous man through 
>   his practice of virtue: great increase of wealth through his
>   diligence; a favorable reputation; a confident deportment, without
>   timidity, in every society, be it that of nobles, brahmans,
>   householders, or ascetics; a serene death; and, at the breaking up of
>   the body after death, rebirth in a happy state, in a heavenly world."

**So, anti-rebirthist & rebirth-lover are pamādo (person who has not meditating mindfulness).**

That is one of many reasons that why I, who have never seen any ghost or any spirit, am not deny next life.

Answer (score 0):

> "So, based on this, how do Secular Buddhists justify their acceptance
>   of the Four Noble Truths and the Buddha's teachings in general, if
>   they reject rebirth? How would the Four Noble Truths and Nibbana have
>   any meaning or usefulness for them? Why would they choose to follow
>   the Noble Eightfold Path, if death is a much simpler way to end
>   suffering?"

You should give this question to the author of the article.

From the article it seems like the author has the belief that rebirth does not exist because there is no evidence for it. If he has such a belief, then his belief is no different than the belief that rebirth exists. In fact, both beliefs are mostly based on "lack of evidence":

The author, due to lack of evidence, believes "there is no rebirth". The religious, due to lack of evidence, believes "there is rebirth". Both are believers. Thus, both have their own religions.

Not only that I don't have a belief in rebirth, but I KNOW that rebirth is true. I was and I am a big skeptic and an agnostic (if I have no proof of something, I neither reject it nor accept it ... I leave it open, but need STRONG proof and evidence before I accept something as true). Nonetheless, regarding spirituality, I was more an atheist then an agnostic. I thought that spiritual and religious beliefs are all made up. I've never read any suttas, nor religious texts, nor books about spirituality, nothing. Never been in the church, nor practiced any religion or spiritual belief nor knew much about them. I was a total skeptic, almost atheist, and gave ZERO attention to spirituality, past lives, God, and similar. During the period when I meditated, I refrained from reading any suttas, religious texts, books about spirituality and similar. I didn't want it to somehow influence my findings and most importantly, if I knew or read about the teachings of the Buddha and similar before attaining my own realizations, how would I know that what I've realized was not just my own imagination under the influence of some teaching, belief, idea, that I've read in some sutta or book about spirituality or religion?? That's why I refrained from reading anything at all. It was only when I got answers to all my questions, that I started to read about God and compared my realizations to what was written in the old texts. I read the Bible and it all made perfect sense to me, but I couldn't 100 % accurately connect it with my own realizations because the texts contained symbolic words and/or stories (example is God which I understood as nonself; heaven which I understood as Nibanna; Satan which I understood as self; hell which I understood as lower realms; "Believe in God and he'll forgive you all your sins" which I understood as "realize nonself and you'll be free from suffering"; the story of Adam and Eve which I understood as volitional activities and thus the birth of self; and similar). It was only when I found Buddhist suttas that everything was written exactly as it is ... no symbolic words nor symbolic stories ... just pure truth. You just can't come closer to the truth in writing.

My message to you is don't accept nor reject anything.

Find a way to TOTALLY calm your mind and observe. Then ask yourself questions. Who am I? How my mind works? Why do I hear sounds through my ears? Is it sound or is it just sound waves vibrating my ear membrane giving raise to sensation in my mind/body, giving raise to thoughts that sound like sound? Why does a thought arise? What's its cause? What is pain? Why does it arise? What is memory? What is remembering? What is time? Just ask questions. Do tests. Do experiments. Be curious. All the answers are in meditation.

Comment: Just a little ontological comment (no vote): you write that you *KNOW* (I don't dispute that you do). But you don't write *why* you *KNOW*. That makes the answer kind of incomplete. Of course, it will still be a subjective account, but nonetheless interesting after your "buildup". :)

Comment: I think that this doesn't answer the question at all, which was, "given that secular Buddhists don't believe in rebirth, why do they accept the 4NT and why do they not end suffering by suicide?"

Comment: @AnoE With a clear and calm mind one must realize anatta. Once anatta is realized, he should study atta. Once atta is realized, he should study volitional activities of the mind as these build atta. Once volitional activities are entirely known, he should search for their cause. The cause is ignorance: volitional activities due to the "want" to liberate from suffering, not knowing that this same activities actually build atta... not knowing that atta is impermanent ... thus creates this whole mass of suffering.The cause is volitional activities arising due to ignorance. Not knowing all this.

Comment: I upvote this answer! If I'm the OP, will choose this the correct answer. The most sound and logical agrument is paragraph 3 & 4, that answered perfectly the question of the dispute on rebirth: *...rebirth does not exist because there is no evidence for it. If he has such a belief, then his belief is no different than the belief that rebirth exists. In fact, both beliefs are mostly based on "lack of evidence"...* *The author...**Both are believers. Thus, both have their own religions.*** Full of wisdom the (bolded) words. Definitely you are authentic meditator! Wisdom from med. Buddha teaches.

Comment: This post is very inspiring to read, I appreciate and learnt, thanks. But your comment has mistake, the talk on Anatta > Atta > volition > ignorance. I think your understanding tainted due to the word *volition*, it's an alien I think because the Sutta translators were coming from background of Biblical doctrine "free will" that's why. So is *Ignorance* not really a correct term to 無明... another hinderance to Buddha's authentic teaching...

Comment: @Mishu I think it all boils down to putting the word 'volition' (sankhara) (second link in 12 nidanas, immediately after ignorance) in the correct context. Me thinking that sankhara means this https://palidictionary.appspot.com/browse/s/sankh%C4%81ra and the best word I can use to describe it from my experience in meditation and outside is "volitional activities" or "wanting" or "building activities" or "all that is created" or "craving" or "deciding" or just "building". Even I can't communicate with one word what it is exactly, so it has sense that this word is very much misunderstood.

Comment: in 12 nidanas, Samskara translated as 行 in Chinese. eng. transl. widely adopted is by Bhikku Bodhi: *formation*. by considering the Chinese and studying wikipedia on Sankhara, i think *reaction/activities* is better, unless i come up with another. to talk *volition*, the better way to understand is rather called *discerning*. the whole mass will conclude as, **due to ignorance, the discerning ability is obscured, created activities/reactions based on wrongly discerned conclusion**.

Comment: of import, it's not something wrong with discerning ability, it always is sound. just like a student who can't produce a sum of certain equation, it's nothing wrong with his brain, he is fine, not mad, or retarded, just that his calculation cannot proceed correctly due to there things he doesn't understand, or somewhere he made mistake.